# Path of a light ray in a medium of varying refractive index

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, geometric-optics

How do we get the equation for the  path of a light ray in a medium of varying refractive index.

I can draw a rough sketch, but don't know how do we get the exact curve.

I encountered this while doing a problem:

> A ray of light travelling in air makes a grazing incidence on a
>   rectangular slab of transparent medium with one vertex at the origin &
>   (sides along x and y axes.)

The refractive index of the material varies as $N=2x$. The path of the light ray is given by?

(The ray makes a grazing incidence nearly parallel to x axis from -ve to +ve x axis  but just enough to enter the first quadrant; where the slab lies.)

Answer (score 4):

Just use snell's law, that is, $\mu \,\sin\theta$=constant, where $\mu$ denotes the refractive index and $\theta$ is the angle between the ray and the normal between a  generic point and the point of incidence.The rest is math, you need to express $\sin\theta$ in terms of the slope at that point and solve the resulting differential equation.