# Integrating over Snell's law with a varying index of refraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, visible-light, refraction

I am working on a research practical and I encountered the problem of having to integrate over Snell's law. The exact problem is that I have a varying index of refraction, which is a function of the height. Now I need to make the exact light trajectory using only the initial height and the initial angle of incidence. I have calculated the path of light numerically using a for loop and diving the light path and I saw that the light path must be part of a parabola.

[image]

This is how the graph looks like with an initial angle of incidence of 89.8 degrees. Now my question is how do I integrate over the path and calculate the light trajectory, because I have been stuck at this problem now for a couple of hours.

Comment: The formula of n as function of the height is too large to add in, but if you want to have a look... https://pastebin.com/cL7bnUjU this is it...

Comment: Use [Fermat's rule](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fermat%27s_principle) instead of Snell's law.

Comment: This looks like a typical problem in calculus of variations.  You will get from this a differential equation which you will have to integrate numerically given the (obscene) dependence of your index of refraction on height.

Comment: How DOES your refractive index vary with height, please?

Comment: I am not allowed to use Fermat's rule, that is my main problem. My Refractive index varies with height with an absurd equation...  https://pastebin.com/LLh6AdwL

Comment: Lets say that the n is a simplified n, with equation ay^2 + by + c, how would I go around the problem then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path of a light ray in a medium of varying refractive index](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210440)