# Estimating the index of refraction using ray tracing?

Tags: refraction

It is possible to figure out the path light will travel if $n(\vec{x})$ is known throughout a material for a particular wavelength. This problem has already been solved.

*Can we do the opposite?*

Let's say we know all the paths that a single wavelength of light can possibly take through a material. Can we theoretically calculate $n(\vec{x})$?

*Is there a method of estimation?*

Let's say we have $N$ known paths of light through a material, $\{\gamma_1,\gamma_2,...,\gamma_N\}$ Can we estimate $n(\vec{x})$?

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. What exactly is your difficulty? I presume you are familiar with Snell's Law. Why can you not apply it to your situation?

Comment: It's not as simple as just applying Snell's Law. Or it might be in some way? Remember $n(\vec{x})$ is now continuous without convenient interfaces or jumps.

If we theoretically know all the paths of light, what are the restrictions on this set of paths so that it is consistent with a nicely behaved $n(\vec{x})$? How do we use that list to find $n(\vec{x})$? There are no obvious interfaces and angles to define for Snell's Law.

For estimating, the paths are not necessarily parallel or perpendicular or nice. What interfaces and angles do we define to use Snell's Law?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path of a light ray in a medium of varying refractive index](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210440/path-of-a-light-ray-in-a-medium-of-varying-refractive-index)

Comment: You use the angle between the ray tangent and the direction in which the refractive index is changing. There is a unique solution if you know that the refractive index only changes in one direction (1D). Otherwise, there are (I think) infinitely many combinations of direction of change and rate of change which can reproduce the same ray path. Data from additional paths will narrow down the choice. Restrictions on how quickly the index or direction can change also help. Definitely a programming task. Mathematics SE and Code Review SE are more suitable for detailed advice.

Comment: I did not put any restrictions on $n(\vec{x})$. (Maybe we should assume that it is in a physics sense 'nice': continuous in first and second derivatives) It is also assumed to be changing in all three directions $(x,y,z)$, which means that we can find a directional derivative to make the problem 1D at a particular point. But then how do we go between points? Is there a general (perhaps coordinate independent) way of dealing with this? I don't think it's as simple as a programming problem just yet.

Answer (score 1):

The [eikonal equation](https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/The_eikonal_equation):
$$ |\nabla T({\bf x})|^2 = \frac{1}{v^2({\bf x})} , $$
relates the spatially varying *traveltime* of an optical field $T({\bf x})$ with the spatially varying propagation speed $v^2({\bf x})$. The former gives information about the paths that light would follow through a medium and the latter can be related to the refractive index
$$ v({\bf x}) = \frac{c}{n({\bf x})} . $$
Therefore, if you know the paths along which the light propagated you should be able to use the eikonal equation to determine the refractive index.